# Jmeter´s WebDriver Sampler - CSS Locator Wildcard

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, jmeter

I´ve been doing some web scrapping using Jmeter´s built-in WebDriver Sampler with Selenium.

**Context:**
At a certain point, i need to select ONLY the pre-selected date that comes out when "opening" a datepicker (that date is always the actual date). Here is a pic showing how it looks like:

[Date Picker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IzoVx.png)

As you can notice, the pre-selected date is 4/4/2022 (today´s date), and the CSS Locator of that specific cell is **#_z_0-w1 > td.z-calendar-cell.z-calendar-weekday.z-calendar-selected**

I´ve tried different ways to aproach this:

1. I tried parsing and passing sysdate (with sendKeys()) using Jmeter´s __time function but it appears that the specific front-end field i´m interacting with expects you to choose from the date picker.
2. I also tried using Xpath to select a sepecific cell from the date picker´s calendar but what i need is to ALWAYS choose the pre-selected date that appears when you open the datepicker.
3. So what i ended up doing is locating the pre-selected date picker´s cell using Selenium´s CSS selector as it follows:

```
//WDS.browser.findElement(pkg.By.cssSelector("#_z_0-w3 > td.z-calendar-cell.z-calendar-weekday.z-calendar-selected")).click();
```

**Issue**:
This worked perfectly fine, but i found out that when the month´s week number changes (for example, from 1, to 2) my script ends up failing because the css selector I´m using specifies the week´s number (#_z_0-**w1** > .....).

In order to solve this issue i need to implement some sort of wildcard character that allows me to always select the cell with that specific css locator regardless of the month´s week number. I´ve been doing my reaserch and tried with different lines of code but i can´t manage to make it work (it always ends up saying that i have a syntax issue or that it can´t find the corresponding web element).

Any sort of help that i could get would be really aprecciated. Also, sorry for my rusty english, it´s not my mother tongue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think CSS Selectors support wildcards in the attributes names

The easiest option is calculating the [current week number](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDate) beforehand and use [string concatenation](https://masteringjs.io/tutorials/fundamentals/string-concat) to insert it into the CSS expression, something like:

```
var currentWeek = Math.floor(new Date().getDate() / 7) + 1
WDS.browser.findElement(pkg.By.cssSelector("#_z_0-w" + currentWeek > td.z-calendar-cell.z-calendar-weekday.z-calendar-selected")).click()
```

More information on the WebDriver Sampler: [The WebDriver Sampler: Your Top 10 Questions Answered](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/webdriver-sampler-your-top-ten-questions-answered)

Comment: Thank you very much! this one worked out. I´ll take in to account that i wont be able to work with wildcards within ccssSelectors.

Thank you Dmitri!